# Django - Filter based on href?

Tags: django

Is there a way to filter based on the href contents {{item.IP_Address}}?
I have a .html page that has a link

```
<td><a href="{% url 'ipDATA' %}">{{item.IP_Address}}</td>
```

I have a function like this:

```
def ipDATA(request, Host=IPs.IP_Address):
    items = NessusReports.objects.filter()
    context = {
        'items': items,
               }
    return render(request, 'nessusdata.html', context)
```

Right now, it returns the entire table, I want to filter based on the href.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters

Comment: Close... but there is no example there of using the link/href string as the parameters for the filter in the function